Downloading an image from a URL using Okio in Kotlin Multiplatform
I'm trying to download an image from a URL using Okio in  Kotlin Multiplatform, but I couldn't find any examples or documentation on how to do this. I have a function that retrieves a wallpaper download URL, and I want to use Okio to download the image. Here's what I have so far:
fun downloadWallpaper(
    wallpaperId: String
) {
    getWallpaperDownloadUrl(wallpaperId) { wallpaperUrl ->
        // Logic to download image
        addMessage(InfoUiMessage(message = Res.string.wallpaper_downloaded))
    }
}

any help would be appreciated

Pretty sure Okio is for local I/O only. You'll need ktor or similar.

Feel free to refer to many sample apps, many of them download a picture at some point - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/kotlin-multiplatform-dev/multiplatform-samples.html. E.g. the Museum app using ktor - https://github.com/Kotlin/KMP-App-Template/blob/main/composeApp/src/commonMain/kotlin/com/jetbrains/kmpapp/data/MuseumRepository.kt, https://github.com/Kotlin/KMP-App-Template/blob/main/composeApp/src/commonMain/kotlin/com/jetbrains/kmpapp/screens/list/ListScreen.kt#L94
